# How to use named routes along with consumer in provider?

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I'm trying to route to a different page at a particular condition in consumer. Although after implementation, I'm getting the following error:
`!_debugLocked: is not true.`

```
Consumer<MyModel>(builder: (context, model, _) {
  if (model.data?.val != null)
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/myRoute');
      return Container(
          child: model.isLoading
                 ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                 : Icon(
                     Icons.camera,
                     color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  ),
               )
            }
```

Comment: The view cannot be redirected to a new page, before the rendering of build method.